# config nginx for multiple nodejs apps

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, nginx

hello i have to config multiple apps of nodejs using nginx...

this is my actual configuration

```
upstream domain.com.ar {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
server {
listen   80;
server_name  www.domain.com.ar;
rewrite ^/(.*) http://domain.com.ar/$1 permanent;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name domain.com.ar;
    #access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.com/access.log;
    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_pass http://domain.com.ar;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

when i use the ip 190.213.125.17:9000 (its just an example of my ip) the app works fine
but when i try to use the domain.com.ar nginx redirect to this page

```
http://domain.com.ar/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi
```

so the app respond with a 404 error configured by me in my app.js like a middleware

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.render('404.jade',
      {
        title: "404 - Page Not Found",
        showFullNav: false,
        status: 404,
        url: req.url
      });
  });
```

there is something wrong in the nginx config???